# Changing data in a Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am changing a few cells of data in a Google spreadsheet. I would like to write back the data into the spreadsheet. The problem i have is that the sheet has say 5 columns, when i add new data into one of the cells i would like to backup the old data in the next free cell in that row. When i do this i am not able to write back the data. This is my code.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("URL");
  var d = sheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses').getDataRange().getValues();
  var head = sheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses').getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

  d[29][2] = "A";
  d[29][3] = "B";
  d[29][4] = "C";
  d[29][5] = "D";
  sheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses').getRange(1,1,d.length,d[0].length).setValues(d);
```

This is the error i get. `Incorrect range width, was 6 but should be 5`

I have also tried modifying the the write back statement as

```
sheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses').getRange(29,1,1,d[29].length).setValues(d[29]);
```

In this case i get `Cannot convert Array to Object[][].`

What is the correct way to write back the data. Preferably i would like to write back data of that particular row only, instead of the whole sheet data.

Comment: you are not specifying what "errors" you are getting. Have you already used the debugger to inspect d? are you starting your array indexes at 1 (incorrect) or at zero (correct)?

Comment: I am starting it with zero indexing only. The response sheet has 5 columns (0 to 4) i would like to add a 6th column which would be the back up data, kinda like a version history of the data. And i will add the errors i get in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you modify only one "row" in the array so that in the end it is not "symetric" anymore (ie every rows don't have the same length) and that causes the error you get.

possible solutions :

There are probably more than one good way to avoid that error, you could create a second array with new data (same height) and join the arrays before writing back to the sheet or, as in the example below, add a cell (or many cells) to every row in the array in a loop before assigning them a new value.  Depending on the size of the array one could be better and/or easier than the other to implement... here is a simplified example that should work :

```
  for(var n=0;n<d.length;n++){
    d[n].push('');
    Logger.log('row '+n+' = '+d[n]+'\n');// see the result
  }
```

---

EDIT following comment :

OR you can write a single row if you change only one, just change the code to

```
sheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses').getRange(29,1,1,d[29].length).setValues([d[29]])
```

which is not far from what you tried but you were simply missing the pair of brackets to get a 2D array as required by `setValues()`

Comment: can't i just write back one single row because i know i will change only one.. seems like a lot of cost(time wise) when i change one row in sa 10000 values.

Comment: of course you can but then you have to write a single row at the right place... I'll edit my answer.

Comment: ok.. i got what i was doing wrong i put d[29] which is an array but [d[29]] is an object.. hence my error. Thanks @Serge